# Jetbrains Rider не видит установленного .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, jetbrains, rider

Установил Jetbrains Rider.

Так как комп был новый - не заметил сразу, что фреймворков не установлено.

После установки Rider установил `.NET Framework 4.8.1`

Но вот беда: Rider этого не заметил.

Когда я захожу в диалог создания нового проекта - то все выглядит как будто я в 16 веке:

(То есть, в списке вообще нет `.NET Framework 4.8.1`)

Как бы мне настроить Rider, чтобы он видел установенный Framework?

Заранее спасибо за советы!

[image: Rider]

Comment: Возможно связано с тем, что райдер условно 32, а фреймворк вы скачали 64 или наоборот (не знаю работает это с .NET Framework, но с VS и .NET это очень даже влияет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно смогу кому-то помочь, но мне помогла чистая установка .net 4.8.1. developers pack. Rider сразу увидел новый фреймворк и дал мне выбирать его в проектах.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший совет!

Answer (score 0):

В общем, как оказалось, есть в Rider вот такая страница конфигурации:

[image: Jetbrains Rider CLI and framework onfiguration]

Comment: И что в итоге? Изменили путь к MSBuild на другой и все заработало?